# Used a model to allow two models in a view but now i can't use foreach on one of them

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022

I have a model that stores two other models as such:

```
public IEnumerable<Character> Characters { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<Class>? Classes { get; set; }
```

the issue is when I try to display all the names of instances of Classes like so:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Classes)
{
    <label><input asp-for="Character.Classes" value="item.Name" type="radio" />item.Name</label>
}
```

I get this error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
> object.

Can anyone help, this is my first time using MVC to make a website.

I have tried Various things to clear the null reference such as:

- an extension method to turn null into empty
- an if to check for null
- using??

the issue may not lie with Classes sometimes being null IDK

Comment: Anyone of those objects (`Model`, `Classes`, `Characters`, `item`) could be null and causing the problem. Do you know which it is?

Comment: Your `foreach` loops on `Classes` but you're displaying `Character.Property` instead of `Classes.Property`. Here, `Character` is probably null but not `Classes`